# Floating point numbers do not match after conversion from equal decimal values

Tags: rust, decimal

To illustrate the issue I have a unit test:

```
#[test]
fn test_decimal_normalize() {
    use rust_decimal_macros::dec;
    let val1 = dec!(5.1);
    let val2 = dec!(-3.51);
    let coef = dec!(0.99);

    let total1 = val1 * coef + val2;
    assert_eq!(dec!(1.539), total1);
    let total1_f = total1.to_f64().unwrap();

    let total2 = Decimal::from_f64(total1_f).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(dec!(1.539), total2);
    let total2 = total2 / coef;
    let total2 = total2 * coef;
    assert_eq!(dec!(1.539), total2);

    let total2_f = total2.to_f64().unwrap();
    // even though we checked above that both Decimal values are equal to 1.539 before
    // converting to f64, the result values are not equal:
    assert_eq!(total1_f, total2_f);
}
```

Can someone explain why the test does not pass?

Comment: Decimal numbers doesn't have an exact representation in binary.

Answer (score 1):

These numbers do end up numerically equal, but they contain different data. They are scaled differently. If you print out the scale and mantissa, you get this:

```rs
println!("{}, {}", total1.scale(), total1.mantissa());
println!("{}, {}", total2.scale(), total2.mantissa());
```

```
3, 1539
28, 15390000000000000000000000000
```

There's a lot of code to handle this in the implementation of equality, but it looks like `to_f64` doesn't do anything to normalize the number. You can do that manually with [`normalize`](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/latest/rust_decimal/struct.Decimal.html#method.normalize) or [`normalize_assign`](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/latest/rust_decimal/struct.Decimal.html#method.normalize_assign).

```rs
let total1_f = total1.normalize().to_f64().unwrap();
let total2_f = total2.normalize().to_f64().unwrap();
```

These `f64` values will be equal.

Comment: Wonder if it should be filed as a bug that the `28, 15390...` scaling converted to f64 yields `1.539000000000000146` compared to the much closer `1.538999999999999924` that the other yields.